# POSIX semaphores in C but still have race conditions?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am trying to understand semaphores, but I cannot figure it out. I think I still have race conditions in my code

The concept is quite simple start this program 4 times using a command line argument -a, -b,-c or -d. Starting order should not matter, but with the following code (see below) it does, and I am not quite sure why.

The printed output should `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` in the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

sem_t *semdes = SEM_FAILED;
char *sem_name = "test";

int main(int argc, char *const *argv)
{
    int opt, res;
    semdes = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 4);
    printf("sem_open() returned %p\n", semdes);
    if (semdes == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        semdes = sem_open(sem_name, 0);
    }
    if ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abcd:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            //printNumbers(1, 5);
            sem_wait(semdes);
            res = sem_wait(semdes);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
            }
            printf("sem_wait() returned %d\n", res);
            printf("%d\n", 1);
            sleep(1);
            sem_post(semdes);
            sem_wait(semdes);
            res = sem_wait(semdes);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
            }
            printf("sem_wait() returned %d\n", res);
            printf("%d\n", 5);
            sleep(1);
            sem_post(semdes);

            break;
        case 'b':
            sem_wait(semdes);
            res = sem_wait(semdes);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
            }
            printf("sem_wait() returned %d\n", res);
            printf("%d\n", 2);
            sleep(1);
            sem_post(semdes);
            //printNumbers(2, 6);
            break;
        case 'c':
            sem_wait(semdes);
            res = sem_wait(semdes);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
            }
            printf("sem_wait() returned %d\n", res);
            printf("%d\n", 3);
            sleep(1);
            sem_post(semdes);
            //printNumbers(3, 7);
            break;
        case 'd':
            sem_wait(semdes);
            res = sem_wait(semdes);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
            }
            printf("sem_wait() returned %d\n", res);
            printf("%d\n", 4);
            sleep(1);
            sem_post(semdes);
            //printNumbers(4, 8);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: unknown option '%c'\n", opt);
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think I fail to understand how semaphores work or I am using the `sem_open` incorrectly.

Using Ubuntu 18.04

**EDIT** This the current output generated

```
sem_open() returned 0x7f5fdbcbf000
sem_wait() returned 0
2
sem_open() returned (nil)
sem_wait() returned 0
3
sem_open() returned (nil)
sem_open() returned (nil)
./n: option requires an argument -- 'd'
ERROR: unknown option '?'
sem_wait() returned 0
1
^C
```

Comment: What *is* the printed output?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I added the output now

Comment: [_"If both O_CREAT and O_EXCL are specified in oflag, then an error is returned if a semaphore with the given name already exists."_](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open) - (also - remove the `:` you have at the end of `"abcd:"`)

Comment: I believe if there are multiple waiters for a semaphore, it's not predictable which (single) waiter gets the wakeup, so these could come out in almost any order as long as 1 is before 5, 2 is before 6, and so on.

Comment: @SeanBright Thanks for that it solved quite a bit!

Comment: @SteveFriedl I think I understand what you mean. So that would mean I would have to have some kind of sync code to guarantee that all processes exists and start them sequentially?

Comment: @Pascalerino Use different semaphores.  When process A finishes, it releases the semaphore process B is sleeping on, which in turn releases the semaphore process C is sleeping on, etc.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That sounds like a great idea! But not quite sure how I would then guarentee Process A being first. Like should I run part A without a semaphore at first only so it can print `1` and then after it wakes up B ?

Comment: Yes, if all of the other processes are sleeping on semaphores, then process A will be the only one that can run, so it will be first by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to Christian idea of using multiple semaphores!

**Final code !**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

sem_t *semA = SEM_FAILED;
sem_t *semB = SEM_FAILED;
sem_t *semC = SEM_FAILED;
sem_t *semD = SEM_FAILED;
sem_t *sem1 = SEM_FAILED;
sem_t *sem2 = SEM_FAILED;
char *nameA = "testa";
char *nameB = "testb";
char *nameC = "testc";
char *nameD = "testd";

int printNumbers(char *name1, char *name2, int no)
{
    //open own semaphore first
    sem1 = sem_open(name1, O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
    int res = sem_wait(sem1);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        perror("PROG: ERROR: sem_wait() failed");
    }
    //printf("sem_wait() of %s returned %d\n", name1, res);
    printf("%d\n", no);
    sem_close(sem1);
    sleep(5);
    //open next semaphore
    sem2 = sem_open(name2, O_CREAT, 0600, 1);
    sem_post(sem2);
    sem_close(sem2);
    return res;
}

void cleanUp()
{
    char name[6] = "testa";
    int res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        res = sem_unlink(name);
        if (res != 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR: sem_unlink() failed");
        }
        printf("sem_unlink() returned %d\n", res);
        name[4] = name[4]+1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *const *argv)
{
    int opt, res;

    if ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abcd")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            // Guarantees 1 is always first since no semaphore
            printf("\n%d\n", 1);
            sleep(5);
            semB = sem_open(nameB, O_CREAT, 0600, 1);
            sem_post(semB);
            sleep(5);
            sem_close(semB);
            printNumbers(nameA, nameB, 5);
            break;
        case 'b':
            printNumbers(nameB, nameC, 2);
            printNumbers(nameB, nameC, 6);
            break;
        case 'c':
            printNumbers(nameC, nameD, 3);
            printNumbers(nameC, nameD, 7);
            break;
        case 'd':
            printNumbers(nameD, nameA, 4);
            printNumbers(nameD, nameA, 8);
            cleanUp();
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: unknown option '%c'\n", opt);
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**With output as :**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
sem_unlink() returned 0
sem_unlink() returned 0
sem_unlink() returned 0
sem_unlink() returned 0
```